# MaxLength not available in MVC Core json result

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

I have developed web API with this method and I test it with **Advanced Rest Client** in my machine and everything is alright, but after deploy to server the result is omitted by the server and not recognize as valid JSON text and not parse correctly.

```
 [Route("[action]")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetAllCityEvent(string apiKey)
    {
        List<CityMapMarker> availableMapMarkers = new List<CityMapMarker>();
        PersianUtilCore.Api.MethodResult result = new PersianUtilCore.Api.MethodResult();
        List<PersianUtilCore.Api.MethodError> errors = new List<PersianUtilCore.Api.MethodError>();

        ApiBO apiBO = new ApiBO(AggregateService);
        bool isValidKey = apiBO.IsValidKey(apiKey);
        if (!isValidKey)
        {
            result.IsSuccess = false;
            errors.Add(new PersianUtilCore.Api.MethodError(300, "your key is not valid!"));
        }
        else
        {
            JunctionBO junctionBO = new JunctionBO(AggregateService);
            StreetBO streetBO = new StreetBO(AggregateService);
            HighwayBO highwayBO = new HighwayBO(AggregateService);
            SightBO sightBO = new SightBO(AggregateService);
            TrafficLightBO trafficLightBO = new TrafficLightBO(AggregateService);
            CameraBO cameraBO = new CameraBO(AggregateService);
            TransportationStationBO bussStationBO = new TransportationStationBO(AggregateService);
            TrafficBO trafficBO = new TrafficBO(AggregateService);
            CityEventBO cityEventBO = new CityEventBO(AggregateService);

            //availableMapMarkers.AddRange(junctionBO.CityMapMarkers());
            //availableMapMarkers.AddRange(streetBO.CityMapMarkers());
            //availableMapMarkers.AddRange(highwayBO.CityMapMarkers());
            //availableMapMarkers.AddRange(sightBO.CityMapMarkers());
            //availableMapMarkers.AddRange(trafficLightBO.CityMapMarkers());
            //availableMapMarkers.AddRange(trafficBO.CityMapMarkers());
            //availableMapMarkers.AddRange(cameraBO.CityMapMarkers());
            availableMapMarkers.AddRange(bussStationBO.CityMapMarkers(TransportationType.Bus));
            availableMapMarkers.AddRange(bussStationBO.CityMapMarkers(TransportationType.Train));
            availableMapMarkers.AddRange(bussStationBO.CityMapMarkers(TransportationType.BRT));
            availableMapMarkers.AddRange(cityEventBO.CityMapMarkers());

            result.Result = availableMapMarkers;
            result.IsSuccess = true;
        }
        result.Errors = errors;
        result.Result = availableMapMarkers;
        result.IsSuccess = errors.Count <= 0;
        var logHistoryResult = apiBO.LogHistory(apiKey, nameof(this.GetAllCityEvent));
        return Json(result);
    }
```

I couldn't find any way to change JsonResult max length like with I did in Asp.net MVC4 or Asp.net Webforms

How can I increase JsonResult maxlength in MVC Core?

Why there is different in IIS publish or local machine when I try to get result from my web API?